# Disadvantage of using --allow-releaseinfo-change for apt-get update

Tags: dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04, apt-get

Refering to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802802/repository-http-security-debian-org-debian-security-buster-updates-inrelease), on Ubuntu 20.04, I know I could add a flag *--allow-releaseinfo-change update* to fix the issue when doing *apt-get update* but what would the cons be by using this flag? What would be the implication going forward? Does it introduce any security issue going forward?

Answer (score 4):

Potentially - "Yes, it does add a risk."

This is evident from reading the documentation on the `--allow-releaseinfo-change` option in `man apt-get`. Specifically, `man apt-secure` describes and discusses its role in ensuring the integrity of the archives from which updates & upgrades are drawn. This risk applies to both signed and unsigned repositories.

The documentation further suggests that this risk may be *mitigated* through the use of `speciality options` that limit acceptable changes to certain fields (labels) in the repo; for example, `suite`. See the documentation for all the details.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the documentation (or specify exactly which man pages) that provides all the details of the speciality options that limit acceptable changes to certain fields? You give the example `suite`, but a comprehensive list with meanings would be more useful!

Comment: @WilliamGallafent: Have you looked at `man apt-get`, followed the references cited there, and in the `SEE ALSO` section of those man pages? IoW - I don't know specifically where these are listed, but if I were keen to know them all, that's where I'd go.