# apt update --allow-releaseinfo-change on different Debian versions

Tags: debian

I have bash script that should run on Debian 9 and newer. It contains `apt-get -qq update` command. With new releases of Debian it is not possible to simply run `apt-get update` on Debian 9 due to new repositories, I get errors like this:

```
E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'
```

`apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` can fix this problem (I know it can be a security issue [Disadvantage of using --allow-releaseinfo-change for apt-get update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849201/disadvantage-of-using-allow-releaseinfo-change-for-apt-get-update) but it does not bother me at the moment).
But it is not possible to run this command on Debian 9:

```
E: Command line option --allow-releaseinfo-change is not understood in combination with the other options
```

I have this workaround:

```
if [ $(lsb_release -cs) == "stretch" ]; then
  apt-get update
else
  apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
fi
```

Is there a better way how to solve this issue?

Comment: "Better" in what sense?

Comment: @ScottHunter The best way is to have same `apt-get update` command for all Debian versions.

Comment: Just wanted to share a solution I came across recently https://serverfault.com/a/1130167/830568